# How select values from multidimensional array to draw graphics?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, highcharts

**have JSON**

```
<c:set var="json_text">
    {
    "FailedCount":[{"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":1,"DATETIME_CURRENT":"12:01"},
    {"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":0,"DATETIME_CURRENT":"12:02"},
    {"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":3,"DATETIME_CURRENT":"12:03"},
    {"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":4,"DATETIME_CURRENT":"12:04"}],
    "SucceededCount":[{"SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":110},
    {"SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":120},
    {"SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":130},
    {"SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":140}]
    }
    </c:set>
```

**prepare data**

```
function culcJson() {
            var jsonObj = ${json_text};
            var VALUES=[];
            var n = jsonObj.FailedCount.length, m = 5;
            var mas = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < m; i++){
                mas[i] = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    if (i==0) {
                        mas[i][j] = jsonObj.FailedCount[j].FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE;
                    }
                    if (i==1)
                    {
                        mas[i][j] = jsonObj.SucceededCount[j].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE;
                    }
                    if (i==2)
                    {
                        mas[i][j] =jsonObj.FailedCount[j].FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE+jsonObj.SucceededCount[j].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE;
                    }
                    if (i==3)
                    {
                    var KPI = jsonObj.SucceededCount[j].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE / (jsonObj.SucceededCount[j].SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE + jsonObj.FailedCount[j].FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE) * 100;
                        mas[i][j] = +KPI.toFixed(2);
                    }
                    if (i==4)
                    {
                        mas[i][j] =jsonObj.FailedCount[j].DATETIME_CURRENT;
                    }
                        VALUES.push(mas[i][j]);
                }}
            console.log(mas);
            return VALUES;
        }
```

**trying to build chart depending KPI from DATETIME**

```
$(function () {

            var VALUES;
            VALUES=culcJson();
            result_newjson.innerHTML = VALUES;

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: {
                    text: '${title}'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ["12:01","12:02","12:03","12:04"]

                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    area: {
                        fillColor: {
                            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                            stops: [
                                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                            ]
                        },
                        marker: {
                            radius: 2
                        },
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        },
                        threshold: null
                    }
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'KPI',               
                       data: [99.5,100,98.56,99.99]
                    }
                ]
            });
        });
```

How to correctly refer to VALUES array to select only the time and KPI instead of static values
categories: ["12:01","12:02","12:03","12:04"] и data: [99.5,100,98.56,99.99]
?

Comment: How exactly do you need to represent the data? If you want it as date, you need to convert "12:01" to timestamp (which includes year/month/day etc.). As two series or one? Depending on that answers you need to do this when you're parsing the json. E.g. https://jsfiddle.net/zn2v79L8/1/

Comment: morganfree, thank you for help, working, problem resolved